# Override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method on click of button

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an app which supports all the orientations but on the click of some button I want to make the app support only current orientation. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The device orientations are really integers. What you can do is have a local variable that you set to the current orientation when the button is clicked and then return only that orientation from the orientation methods. If that integer is not set, return the orientation of the device. Also note that shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation has been deprecated in iOS 6.0. From the docs:

```
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation : (Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Override the supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation methods instead.)
```

EDIT: Here's the reference for UIInterfaceOrientation.

> typedef enum : NSInteger {
>      UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
>      UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
>      UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
>      UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
>   } UIInterfaceOrientation;